# Improve cufon font performance on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, performance, cufon

I'm using the Cufon font replacement tool on iPhone.  Unfortunately, it's really slow there.  (On a small 50 word page it takes about 2 seconds on my first-gen iPhone.)

Are there any optimizations I can make to improve performance?  (If you have multiple tips, please split them out into multiple answers so they can be voted up separately.)

Comment: I can only stress: don't do it.. You're really not helping your users with a prettier font if it slows them down so much. I doubt you can make it much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that there IS something I can do to make it a lot faster: avoid forcing Cufon to iterate over non-text nodes.  By passing explicit divs to replace, Cufon performance considerably improved; it's now well under a second.